# How can I change the number of cards in a Bootstrap row with media queries?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let card of cards">
```

This div holds cards that are displayed on the webpage. As it stands when the screen size is XL 4 cards will be displayed, large 3, medium 2, and small 1.

Now let's say I am on the largest screen size and start dragging the window to make it smaller, everything works as it should, however, when nearing the end of the XL screen size the cards begin to overlap horizontally. This also happens between 3 cards being shown and 2 cards being shown.

I've targeted the areas where there is overlap using the @media selector, and I made the background color red for testing purposes. This is what it looks like:

```
  @media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1450px) {
      background-color: red; // Test if this is applied
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 990px) and (max-width: 1050px) {
    background-color: red;           
  }
```

My question is what can I do to adjust the amount of cards being displayed so that in the first @media tag instead of displaying 4 cards it displays 3.

And for the second @media tag what can I do so it displays 2 instead of 3 cards.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <!-- card markup here, please -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be battling against the Bootstrap grid here. I suggest excising Angular from this post and simply posting a Bootstrap demo using the editor. Then we can actually see the behavior and make sensible suggestions.

Comment: I've put a skeleton in your post. Please either update it or remove it if you won't use it. Partly we need to see the card content, which is presumably what causes the overlap.

Comment: You might also explain why using wider columns isn't a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change col-xl-3 ---> col-xl-4  = 3 columns

Change col-lg-4 ---> col-lg-6  = 2 columns

The bootstrap grid is twelve columns wide.

col-size-x will display 12/x cards.

*Do not alter the media queries!*