# Cards are overlapping Boostrap Breakpoints not doing anything

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have some cards displayed on the screen, there are 4 cards per row on XL screen size, 3 cards per row on large, 2 per medium, and 1 per small.

When I change the screen size this works well, however, there are some spots where the cards overlap. I've tried using the flex breakpoints to change the number of cards from 4 to 3 sooner when I am dragging the screen size down. I want to do the same from 3 to 2 cards since there is also an overlap.

Here is how I coded it if you want to reproduce it:

Card Component:
HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container" id="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            {{fruit}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 8rem;

  border: solid 1.7px #c5c5c5;

}
```

TS:

```
export class CardComponent {
  @Input() fruit = ""


}
```

Now Here is the parent component:
HTML:

```
<div class="businesses-container">
    <div class="row business-cards-section">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
            <div class="business-card-container">
                <app-card [fruit]="fruit">
                </app-card> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.businesses-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;

    .business-cards-section {
        max-width: 1700px;

        .business-card-container {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
          
    }
}
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'cards';
  fruits = ["apple", "banana", "strawberries", "lemon", "pineapple", "kiwi"]
}
```

Now here is what I've tried adding to my parent component CSS to prevent overlap.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 1070px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 1500px,
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 1070px,
  lg: 1500px,
);
```

I have added the following breakpoints. The problem is they don't seem to be doing anything. I set large to 1500px because I want it to switch from xl to l right before the overlap. Same thing for medium.

Comment: Why does this seem like a reformulation of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77574606/how-can-i-change-the-number-of-cards-in-a-bootstrap-row-with-media-queries)?